# {IEEEtran} to jpconf

Tags: document-classes

I used this `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}` to prepare the document. However I need to convert into `\documentclass[a4paper]{jpconf}`. How do I do this? How do I change the title and margin?

I used the following code to start the document

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum, babel}
 \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{nicefrac,amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper, tmargin=1.5in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in, rmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%the following are the packages used to make greek letters bold
\usepackage{bm}
\bmdefine{\bX}{X}
\bmdefine{\bi}{i}
\bmdefine{\bMinus}{-}
\bmdefine{\bSum}{\sum}
\bmdefine{\bLeft}{(}
\bmdefine{\bRight}{)}

\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float} %figure[H]
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The `jpconf` document class may be somewhat uncommon; for sure, it is not distributed with TeXLive. Is it available online somewhere?

Comment: Off-topic: Unless your TeX distribution is positively ancient, there should be no need for the `epstopdf` package.